# Valgrind: Difference between Invalid Read and Segfault

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

So I'm getting to know valgrind a bit and I've come across an example that has me confused.

I was shown this code causes a Invalid Write in valgrind:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

 #include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    int index = atoi(argv[1]);

    char *x = malloc(10);

    x[index] = ‘f’;

    return 0;

}
```

while this code causes a segfault in valgrind:

```
int foo(y)
{

    char str[10];

    str[11] = ‘f’;

    return 0

}
```

So do these examples have anything to do with the fact that example 1 is something thats done on the heap while the 2nd example is done on the stack?

Am I missing something bigger?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it's all undefined behavior, so who really knows? And the first depends greatly on what you pass as a command line argument. But yes, the first is likely to corrupt heap while the second is likely to smash your stack.

Comment: The second code block shouldn't even compile, you can't use curly quotes in C.

Comment: @Barmar: Actually, both code blocks have that. But valid point.